# Store an object in redux state as value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Let's say I have an object of key-value pair as following:

Obj1 as:

```
    { 
        'a' : ["1", "2", "3"...],
        'b' : ["6", "3", "1",...],
         ...
         ...
    }
```

Obj2 as :

```
    { 
        'a' : "Football",
        'b' : "Volleyball",
         ...
         ...
    }
```

The key-value pairs of the obj1 and obj2 are returned from the api, and have no control over it.

I want to store it in these both object in state as :
sportsCode: obj2,
teamPlayers: obj1.

When I set it in the state with action, the state is updated correctly, but not able to retrieve with reducer, it says the value is undefined.

Comment: Show us what you are trying to do, how you are setting the values in redux state and how you are trying to retrieve them.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution to the problem. I was setting the state correctly, but not retriving properly in mapStateToProps. Installing the chrome plugin [ReduxDevTools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redux-devtools/lmhkpmbekcpmknklioeibfkpmmfibljd/related?hl=en) helped in figuring it out quickly.

thanks for the efforts.